# Meaning of "pull one's lips"

Tags: meaning

from "Collectors" by Raymond Carver.

His(Aubrey's) eyes had lighted and then dimmed at the sight of the carpet. He shuddered. Then he took off his coat...
Aubrey Bell stared at the carpet. He **pulled his lips**. Then he laughed. He laughed and shook his head.
What's so funny? I said.
Nothing. Lord, he said. He laughed again. I think I'm losing my mind...

In this content, does "He pulled his lips" mean same as "He pursed his lips"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this content, does "He pulled his lips" mean same as "He pursed his lips"?

No. It means he literally pulled at his lips with his hand.